# Disabling submit buttons before postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, submit, postback

I wanted to disable all submit buttons on a page before postback. Found 3 (slightly) different code samples but none is working in my scenario.

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(new function () {
        //debugger;

        // 1
        $('#form1').one('submit', function () {
            alert('.one');
            $(this).find('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        });

        // 2
        $("#form1").submit(function () {
            alert('.submit1');
            $('input[type=submit]').click(function () { return false; });
        });

        // 3
        $("#form1").submit(function () {
            alert('.submit2');
            $('input[type=submit]').click(false);
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML (from View Source):

```
<body>
    <form method="post" action="WebForm12.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMjA0OTM4MTAwNGRk6dbofDK5YUWMwPmdBDnRWPCTyBN22BpAo7Y3C+2Gycs=" />
</div>

<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWAgKC36LkAgKr4aeRA6gaPoGNYlZvnjW07iB+LnlhIUr0qrTFHOADKmQQuhv0" />
</div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" name="btnPost" value="Post" id="btnPost" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

## Update

Well, as indicated by **putvande** the actual issue was the *new* keyword in defining the ready event function. However, the code samples were still not serving the objective.

**Sample 1** didn't actually run the relevant OnClick handler, as it didn't postback the button's value to the server due to being disabled.

**Sample 2/3** prevented the subsequent postbacks at a time, but left the button enabled on the UI.

Further search ended up with more suitable technique to resolve the issue. The code below uses onbeforeunload event to disable submit buttons perfectly.

```
window.onbeforeunload = DisableButtons;

function DisableButtons() {
    $("input[type=submit]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

Comment: I don't think your first example will work since you use an old version of jQuery. But what are you trying to do? After hitting the submit button, you want to disable the submit button?

Comment: @putvande yes. to avoid resubmit while postback in process.

Comment: It in fact not reaching the `alerts` though

Comment: Are you using all 3 examples in your code at once? I think the first one (`$('#form1').one('submit'...`) gives you an error, right?

Comment: using one at a time. no error. nothing happens. even it doesn't reach the alerts.

Comment: .one() is added in version 1.1  
http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your events never get assigned to your `form`.
You need to change:

```
$(document).ready(new function () {
                  ^^^
```

To:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

If you change that the submit functions will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
return false;
```

Comment: It in fact not reaching the `alerts` though

Answer (score 0):

In a way, you can do this as explained below.

You can add one more button with display:none. In the visible button javascript click event, you can disable this button and invoke the click of hidden button (document.getElementById('btnHidden').click()).

The actual code that needs to be executed on visible button click goes into event handler of the hidden button.

**Update:**

I didn't assume a bigger picture.. If application wide, you might want to consider this..

For the button OnClientClick you can assign this function...

```
function disableButton(btnID)
{
     setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById(btnID).style.background = "disabled.jpg";}, 10);
     document.getElementById(btnID).disabled = true;
     return true;
}
```

"disabled.jpg" is a background that you can assign to background which gives a disabled look to the button.

This way, momentarily you can give disabled look for the user; but that is for a very minimal time that, by this the form would have already posted to server.

Comment: your workaround may work. however, i want to implement it application-wide using master page and jQuery.